# Combining result sets into a single table after `For Do Loop` in Big Query

Tags: sql, loops, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I understand how to loop using the below syntax in Google BigQuery - but this gives me a separate result set for each iteration of the loop. If I run the below code that gives me 5 result sets each with a single row of data. What I need is a way to combine the 5 result sets into a single table with 5 rows.

```
FOR record IN
  (SELECT word, word_count
   FROM bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare
   LIMIT 5)
DO
  SELECT record.word, record.word_count;
END FOR;
```

I'm not trying to get 5 records from the Shakespeare sample. The above piece of code is just an example for the FOR DO LOOP. What i want to do is more complicated but follows the same logic. Basically iterate over an array of values do some aggregation and combine the results into a single table.

Using the sample code above, I get different result set for each iteration as you can see in the image below, what i need my query to do is to combine the results after each iteration into a single table and give me just 1 result set.
[image: Query result]

Comment: What are you trying to do here? If you are trying to get 5 records from the Shakespeare sample you just need: SELECT word, word_count
   FROM bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare
   LIMIT 5

Comment: Can you give an example of what the bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare table contains and what result table you expect? That makes it easier to help you.

Comment: @JeremySavage Can you post your comment as answer?

Comment: @JeremySavage I edited the question to add more context. Thank you!

Comment: it is hard to answer heavily obfuscated questions! you should show more reasonable example of what you try to achieve so you have better chances to get the answer you expect!

Comment: @praneethkandula please can you add your desired output - I understand what you are currently getting, but I am unsure what you *want* to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can accumulate different results into one variable and then select this one variable in the end.

```
DECLARE results ARRAY<STRUCT<word STRING, word_count INT64>> DEFAULT [];
DECLARE single_result STRUCT<word STRING, word_count INT64>; 

FOR record IN
  (SELECT AS STRUCT word, word_count
   FROM bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare
   LIMIT 5)
DO
  SET single_result = (SELECT AS STRUCT record.word, record.word_count);
  SET results = ARRAY_CONCAT(results, single_result);
END FOR;

SELECT * FROM UNNEST(results);
```

Your query will still return multiple resutls but at least you'll be able to click on the last one and see the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the central part:

```
SELECT word, word_count FROM bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare LIMIT 5
```

SQL automatically loops through the rows in the table during the select statement. This can be affected by using `WHERE` to exclude certain rows.